# JMeter Master CommandLine Run is not passing the updated values from -J flag to the slaves

Tags: jmeter, master-slave

I have a single master and 5 slave agents. I am starting my test using the command line option from the master by specifying the slave machines using the -R option.

```
$JMETER_HOME/current/bin/jmeter -n -t test.jmx -R host1,host2  -l testresult.jtl -Jthreads=$THREADS -Jrampup=$RAMPUP -Jtestduration=$TESTDURATION -JENV=$ENV -e -o ./testreport
```

I see that the new values that are passed in the command line using the -J switch are not getting applied when the test plan is transferred to the slave machines. Slaves are using only the hardcoded values in the JMX.

Comment: Did you define the properties in the jmx with the _P function?

Comment: Yes. I did. All the values that are used in -J have been defined inside the JMX using the _P function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Jmeter Doc on [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

```
-J[prop_name]=[value]
defines a local JMeter property.
-G[prop_name]=[value]
defines a JMeter property to be sent to all remote servers.
```

So, you need to use `-G` flag for Jmeter property to be sent to all remote servers.

Comment: To add, see here: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html ;-)

Comment: As a side note, I see that -J option and -G has to be duplicated in the same line if we want to use the script for both standalone master testing with 1 machine OR master-slave configuration. If we use -G option alone, only master-slave configuration works. Same way, -J allows only the single agent master configuration.